# `replace` not working as expected on AWS CDK api_endpoint value

Tags: python, aws-cdk

I have a section of AWS CDK Code;

```
distribution = Distribution(
            self,
            self.config.get_resource_name("api distribution"),
            default_behavior=BehaviorOptions(
                origin= HttpOrigin(domain_name='origin-source-code.com')),
            additional_behaviors={
                f"{self.config.SUB_DOMAIN}/*": BehaviorOptions(
                    origin=HttpOrigin(domain_name=api_endpoint.replace('https://', '')),
                    allowed_methods=AllowedMethods.ALLOW_ALL,
```

Note specifically, this line;

```
origin=HttpOrigin(domain_name=api_endpoint.replace('https://', '')),
```

I've verified, via CfnOutput that the api_endpoint value is this;

```
desi-dummy-api-api-gateway.httpapiendpointoutput = https://<secret>.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
```

But, I continue to get this error;

```
Resource handler returned message: "Invalid request provided: The parameter origin name cannot contain a colon.
```

[edit]

The api_endpoint is a token:

```
print(f"API_ENDPOINT = {api_endpoint}")
API_ENDPOINT = ${Token[TOKEN.425]}
```

This doesn't seem to fix the error;
origin=HttpOrigin(domain_name=Token.as_string(api_endpoint).replace('https://', ''))

Comment: `replace` is applied at synth-time, when `api_endpoint` may be an unresolved [Token](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/tokens.html).  What value do you you get when you `print(api_endpoint)`?

Comment: @fedonev  (thanks), I updated the question to include the output of the print statement.

Comment: Based on the documentation link you sent me (thanks) I'll try the following; origin=HttpOrigin(domain_name=Token.as_string(api_endpoint).replace('https://', ''))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace is applied at synth-time, when `api_endpoint` is an unresolved [Token](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/tokens.html) value.  To work around this, use [CloudFormation intrinsic functions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/python/aws_cdk/Fn.html) to defer the substitution to deploy-time:

```py
domain_name = cdk.Fn.select(2, cdk.Fn.split("/", api_endpoint))
```

Comment: Awesome-sauce, that did the trick, Not sure I would have found that on my own -- thanks.